# Is there any reward for collecting stamps?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

While playing Super Mario 3D World I've been collecting stamps throughout various levels, but far from all of them. Still, I've gathered a decent amount, and as far as I can tell there hasn't been any reward for doing so.

Is there any reward for collecting them, or were they just meant to be posted to Miiverse while that still was up?

Comment: I think you can also use them in Capture mode now which is new.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## World Crown

> How to Unlock World Crown. Super Mario 3D World's final bonus level is also the game's most elusive unlockable. In order to access World Crown, you'll need to unlock every Green Star, **earn every Stamp**, and reach the top of the flag pole on every level. You'll be able to access the game's final world from there. [Source](https://www.denofgeek.com/games/super-mario-3d-world-every-unlockables-guide/)

Comment: You don't actually need *every* stamp to unlock crown world - you simply need every stamp *besides* the character stamps (which require beating every level with each character).